# Vector and RMS averaging in FFT

Tags: python, python-3.x, signals, signal-processing, fft

I have a data array on which I have performed an FFT. This is the code that I have applied.

```
import numpy as np

# "data" is a column vector on which FFT needs to be performed
# N = No. of points in "data" 
# dt = time interval between two corresponding data points

FFT_data         = np.fft.fft(data)       # Complex values
FFT_data_real    = 2/N*abs(FFT_data)      # Absolute values
```

However, I went through following link: https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1159.php

Here it says, to enhance the SNR we can apply "RMS-averaged FFT" and "Vector Averaged FFT".

Can somebody please let me know how to we go about doing these two methodologies in Python or is there any documentation/links to which we can refer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [your reference](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/1159.php) indicates:

> If you take the square root of the average of the squares of your sample spectra, you are doing *RMS Averaging*. Another alternative is *Vector Averaging* in which you average the real and complex components separately.

Obviously to be able to perform either averaging you'd need to have more than a single data set to average. In your example code, you have a single column vector `data`. Let's assume you have multiple such column vectors arranged as a 2D `N`x`M` matrix, where `N` is the number of points per dataset and `M` is the number of datasets. Since the datasets are stored in columns, when computing the FFT you will need to specify the parameter `axis=0` to compute the FFT along columns.

**RMS-averaged FFT**

As the name suggests, for this method you need to take the square-root of the mean of the squared amplitudes. Since the different sets are stored in columns, you'd need to do the average along the axis 1 (the other axis than the one used for the FFT).

```
FFT_data        = np.fft.fft(data, axis=0)  # Complex values
FFT_data_real   = 2/N*abs(FFT_data)         # Absolute values
rms_averaged    = np.sqrt(np.mean(FFT_data_real**2, axis=1))
```

**Vector Averaged FFT**

In this case you need to obtain the real and imaginary components of the FFT data, then compute the average on each separately:

```
FFT_data        = np.fft.fft(data, axis=0)  # Complex values
real_part_avg   = 2/N*np.mean(np.real(FFT_data),axis=1)
imag_part_avg   = 2/N*np.mean(np.imag(FFT_data),axis=1)
vector_averaged = np.abs(real_part_avg+1j*imag_part_avg)
```

Note that I've kept the `2/N` scaling you had for the absolute values.

**But what can I do if I really only have one dataset?**

If that dataset happens to be stationary and sufficiently large then you could break down your dataset into smaller blocks. This can be done by reshaping your vector into an `N`x`M` matrix with the following:

```
data = data.reshape(N,M)
...
```

Then you could perform the averaging with either method.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SleuthEye for your valuable feedback.